# Reference request for an identity involving Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs, catalan-numbers

I am wondering if a bijective proof of the following identity involving Catalan generating functions has appeared anywhere in the literature. (It's not difficult to simply verify it for the functions involved, so a bijective proof is the interesting part here.)

Let $C_n=\displaystyle\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$, $C(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{C_nz^n}=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$, and $C_{\text{odd}}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{C_{2n+1}z^n}=\dfrac{C(\sqrt{z})-C(-\sqrt{z})}{2\sqrt{z}}$. Then
$$
(zC(z))\circ(zC(4z))=zC_{\text{odd}}(z),
$$
where $\circ$ denotes composition of functions. Expressed in terms of the coefficients of these functions, this yields, after a few cancellations,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\binom{n+k}{k}4^k}=\binom{4n+1}{2n},
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-k}{n-k}4^{n-k}}=\binom{4n+1}{2n}.
$$

*Update:* The identity $(zC(z))\circ(zC(4z))=zC_{\text{odd}}(z)$ can be thought of as a companion to Shapiro's Catalan identity for $C_{\text{even}}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{C_{2n}z^n}=\dfrac{C(\sqrt{z})+C(-\sqrt{z})}{2}$, namely, that
$$
C(4z)=C_{\text{even}}(z)^2.
$$

Comment: How are you getting $(zC(z))\circ(zC(4z))=zC_{\text{odd}}(z)$?

Comment: @robjohn For example, you can invert $zC(z)$ to obtain $z-z^2$. So you can just verify that $zC(4z)=zC_{\text{odd}}(z)(1-zC_{\text{odd}}(z))$.